# dynamically adding image src using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add an image src into an image in div on click of a thumbnail. The problem is that the image src do not change when another thumnail is clicked.

HTML Code is:

```
  <a class="thumbnail" href="#" >
     <img  src="img1">
     <img  src="img2">
     <img  src="img3">
  </a>



 <div  class="imageforthumb">
    <img class="imageforthumbs">
 </div>
```

Javascript im using is:

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function () {
var images = $('.thumbnail img').attr('src');
$(".imageforthumbs").attr('src', images)
});
```

once i click the first image img1, it is set to img1 and do not change to img2 when i click the thumbnail. Please advice what could be wrong here ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your js code is incorrect. try

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function (eve) {
    $(".imageforthumbs").attr('src', $(eve.target).attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: ha, another race condition ;-). if this solution caters for your needs, accept Jamiec's conceptually identical answer which was submitted a few moments before mine.

Comment: Thanks very much. That work with slight addition of 'img' in front of .thumbnail

 $('.thumbnail img').click(function () {
    $(".imageforthumbs").attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});

Answer (score 2):

With this line:

```
var images = $('.thumbnail img').attr('src');
```

You're always getting the first image's `src`.

Change your code to:

```
$('.thumbnail img').click(function () {
    var images = $(this).attr('src');
    $(".imageforthumbs").attr('src', images)
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/8hTrr/

---

Edit: As pointed out, you dont need jQuery to get the `attr`, you just need:

```
$('.thumbnail img').click(function () {
     $(".imageforthumbs").attr('src', this.src)
});
```

Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/8hTrr/1/

Answer (score 0):

Delegate the event to each image within the `<a></a>` tag. Then bind the src of the clicked `<img />`.

```
$('.thumbnail').on('click', 'img', function () {
    $(".imageforthumbs")[0].src = this.src;
});
```